# WinDbg range error while searching jump

Tags: reverse-engineering, windbg, buffer-overflow, exploit

I am trying to search jump in a programs' dll but when I do that I am taking range error. What's the problem with that?

My WinDbg output is below:

```
0:000> g
ModLoad: 76390000 763ad000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.DLL
ModLoad: 773d0000 774d3000   C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.2600.5512_x-ww_35d4ce83\comctl32.dll
.
.
.
ModLoad: 10000000 10094000   C:\Program Files\SoriTong\Player.dll
ModLoad: 42100000 42129000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\wmaudsdk.dll
ModLoad: 00fd0000 0101f000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRMClien.DLL
ModLoad: 5bc60000 5bc9f000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\strmdll.dll
ModLoad: 71ad0000 71ad9000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\WSOCK32.dll
ModLoad: 71ab0000 71ac7000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
ModLoad: 71aa0000 71aa8000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2HELP.dll
ModLoad: 76eb0000 76edf000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\TAPI32.dll
ModLoad: 76e80000 76e8e000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\rtutils.dll
(830.964): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for SoriTong.exe
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for SoriTong.exe - 
eax=00130000 ebx=00000003 ecx=00000070 edx=00000070 esi=0017f4f4 edi=0012fd64
eip=00422e33 esp=0012da14 ebp=0012fd38 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00010212
SoriTong!TmC13_5+0x3ea3:
00422e33 8810            mov     byte ptr [eax],dl          ds:0023:00130000=41
0:000> s 10000000 l 10094000 ff e4
                           ^ Range error in 's 10000000 l 10094000 ff e4'
```

Comment: Do you have the valid pdb for SoriTong.exe? You can do a check using `!itoldyouso SoriTong`, also check your build settings and maybe try against debug version

Comment: Looking at the error message I think you have specified incorrect parameters, the `s` command only takes into account `l` flag for strings, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff558855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) what is it you are trying to do?

Comment: @EdChum I tried !itoldyouso SoriTong but I dont know what that means.                                                           0:000> !itoldyouso SoriTong

SoriTong.exe
    Timestamp: 37DEE000
  SizeOfImage: DE000
      pdb sig: 0
          age: 0

Comment: do you see MATCH in the output? This will say whether you have the correct pdbs or not, it looks like you don't, see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debuggingtoolbox/archive/2009/09/04/special-command-using-chksym-itoldyouso-to-check-pdb-files-against-modules.aspx) but I think your `s` command looks wrong as the limits and parameters look wrong, check the MSDN link in my previous comment

Answer (score 6):

You should use s -b (as type) before Range Pattern

This works for me:

```
0:004> lm mkernel32
start    end        module name
7c800000 7c8f6000   kernel32   (pdb symbols)  

0:004> s -b 7c800000 7c8f6000   ff e4
7c86467b  ff e4 47 86 7c ff 15 58-15 80 7c 8d 85 38 fe ff  ..G.|..X..|..8..
```

Yes jmp found

```
0:004> u 7c86467b  
kernel32!UnhandledExceptionFilter+0x7fc:
7c86467b ffe4            jmp     esp
7c86467d 47              inc     edi
7c86467e 867cff15        xchg    bh,byte ptr [edi+edi*8+15h]
```

I don't think .pdb is relevant